# Failed To enable Specific key into online games

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Hello i test my project and it work good in desktop, even into game chat, but in game environment, not work..

[image: Interface]

> {{{{KeyboardHook}}} : (((Class)))

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class KeyboardHook

<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As KBDLLHookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Private Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    Public vkCode As UInt32
    Public scanCode As UInt32
    Public flags As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
    Public time As UInt32
    Public dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr
End Structure

<Flags()>
Private Enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As UInt32
    LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1
    LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10
    LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20
    LLKHF_UP = &H80
End Enum

Public Shared Event KeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys)
Public Shared Event KeyUp(ByVal Key As Keys)

Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105

Private Delegate Function KBDLLHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

Private KBDLLHookProcDelegate As KBDLLHookProc = New KBDLLHookProc(AddressOf KeyboardProc)
Private HHookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
        Dim struct As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Select Case wParam
            Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
                RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
            Case WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYUP
                RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
        End Select
    End If
    Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
End Function

Public Sub New()
    HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
    If HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
        Throw New Exception("Could not set keyboard hook")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    If Not HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHookID)
    End If
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub


End Class
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=

> {{{Form1}}} : (((Vb)))

```
  Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents kbHook As New KeyboardHook

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown


    Debug.WriteLine(Key.ToString)
    If Key.ToString() = "G" Then
        SendKeys.Send("R")
    End If

    If Key.ToString() = "J" Then
        SendKeys.Send(" ")
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub kbHook_KeyUp(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyUp
    Debug.WriteLine(Key)
End Sub

End Class
```

That all i hope some help , I already test code and work, but not into game Event's

So when i Click in (g) key , will reload using (r) key presser, also when i click on (j) key will click on SpaceBar key To jumb into game . that all, i dont forward to make any cheat, it only for get some knowledge.

## updated (provide code.)

Comment: Please provide code...

Comment: it say code tooo match, so i uploaded by private link,

Comment: okey i updated provide code,, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SendKeys` doesn't always work in games. Try my library called *InputHelper* instead ([**Download from GitHub**](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases)). It has two different methods of performing input simulation and includes an easy-to-use keyboard hook.

Just make sure you include its copyright license somewhere with or within your application, where it is easy to find for the user.

```
Imports InputHelperLib

Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents KeyboardHook As New InputHelper.Hooks.KeyboardHook

    Private Sub KeyboardHook_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As InputHelperLib.InputHelper.Hooks.KeyboardHookEventArgs) Handles KeyboardHook.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.G
                InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.R)

            Case Keys.J
                InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.Space)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

If this doesn't work there are two other alternative ways to send key presses with that you can try.

**Either:**

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.G
        InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.R, True)

    Case Keys.J
        InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.Space, True)
End Select
```

**Or:**

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.G
        InputHelper.WindowMessages.SendKeyPress(Keys.R)

    Case Keys.J
        InputHelper.WindowMessages.SendKeyPress(Keys.Space)
End Select
```

I haven't documented the rest of the library yet, but on my project's [**Wiki**](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/wiki) you can find information about how the hooks work.

All the methods have XML documentation added to them though, so Visual Studio's IntelliSense will show you what they and their parameters do. You can also press <kbd>F12</kbd> in VS and look at all of InputHelper's members in the Object Browser.

---

Note that some games only accept raw hardware input (i.e. reading directly from the keyboard/mouse). If this is the case for the game you're trying this with, then most solutions that you find won't work.

The regular ways of simulating input is either to append it to the system's mouse and keyboard input stream, or to send a key press message (window message) to the game window. However the game will ignore these if it only takes raw input directly from the input devices.

You can try googling *"DirectX input simulation"* or *"DirectInput input simulation"*, but I doubt you'll find anything useful.

Comment: i downloaded InputHelper.dll, and add this refrence into project , then deleted all form1.vb  , { 1 , 2 , 3 case's not works} And added Your First Case (first case, i try after that either {only deleted case and replace with either}, i try after that {only deleted either case and replace with or})

Case's (1, 2 , 3) not of them worked, still not appear anything yet.

Photo : https://imgur.com/1Tk42Si

Comment: i also tried to put my old code without delete it and add your code there ,, it same ,, only my old code work, not your's

Comment: @ibrahimamen : Oh my... I forgot to add `New` in `Dim KeyboardHook As New InputHelper.Hooks.KeyboardHook`. I've updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: Sorry bro but it not work again after your last edit, again :( in the game, Oo

i wounder why it not work in games Oo, did you test it in any game :( i dont think tho :( , thats strange

Comment: @ibrahimamen : What game/games are you trying to use this with? I've tried `InputHelper` only with a couple of games but so far I've not had any problems with it. However some games rely solely on raw hardware input, meaning they ignore Windows's mouse and keyboard input stream. If this is the case then there's not much you can do (a least not in VB.NET).

Comment: @ibrahimamen : As I said there's not much you can do if the game only takes raw input. You could search for something like "DirectX input simulation" or "DirectInput input simulation", but I doubt you'll find anything that works.

Comment: okey i will search on it,,

big thanks Bro,, i made that Accept your answer, thanks bro

Comment: @ibrahimamen : I added the info to the bottom of my answer as well. Good luck!

Comment: @ibrahimamen : I just tested my **"Either"** code with CS:GO. It works perfectly for me. Are you sure you're not doing something wrong? Based on your screenshot, I hope you are running this on a Windows computer with a Mac theme... Or are you actually using a Mac?

Comment: i using win 7 , Mac theme,, 

i already want tried it with cs:go and it worked perfectly, but not work with s4league,, is my code have something wrong,,

Comment: @ibrahimamen : Okay, just checking. Well then S4 League has a different way of handling input, your code is not the problem (apart from that it doesn't work with that game). You keep searching, I hope you find something.

Comment: Big thanks i solved and got everything and all works Too ,, big thanks for your solve , i apply now to get knowledge with InputHelper, and Hook ,,, Etc..

Comment: @ibrahimamen : Glad I could help! May I ask what the problem was?

Comment: i used a Autoit to preforme that ,, so after recorded key into Autolit, i made a key detected if it Pressed a "j" will go in my refrence and open that Recorder 

Autoit Recorer Exe. so i saved into reference so after detect that "j"
key will go play that autoit exe from reference, that all

but unfortunatly your (Code, Either,  or) Not worked with that game S4league

-= but work with me when i use Autoit, but have some lag when it run, it slow respawn to perform that jumb atleast i will jumb after 2 , 3 secound after my "j" key pressed, :(

Comment: aha,, you mean to get autoit script code add put it into InputHelper.xml , so is that will work Oo

Comment: @ibrahimamen : No that's not what I meant. Either way I misread the code, so ignore what I said before. -- The odd thing is, looking at AutoIt's source code it uses similar methods as mine, only mine is more up-to-date.

Comment: yes it up-to-date, cause i made alote of testing before put it into reference .

Comment: @ibrahimamen : By the way, "replicate" means that you try to make something behave like something else. In this case trying to make my code behave like AutoIt's. _**Not**_ copying the code. -- As I said though I was mistaken. What I initially thought was not the case.

Comment: @ibrahimamen : I don't see what there could possibly be to edit in my code right now, but sure. As long as you follow the copyright license it's fine. ;)